# How to assign a mocked object to a object in controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I have a controller which contains a `business` class that internally has dependencies to a `datahandler`. For testing that business class I need to mock the `datahandler`. After setup, I am assigning the business class' `datahandler` with the mocked `datahandler`. But while debugging, the business class' `datahandler` is showing null , I know that I should use the constructor to inject the mocked object.But is it possible to do it without using any constructor injection ?Can any body help me with this?

my business class:

```
public class FooBusiness
{
  public static BarDataHandler _barDatahandler = new BarDataHandler();
  ...
}
```

Test class:

```
public class FooBusinessTest
{
  ...
  _mockedBarDataHandler = new Mock<IBarDataHandler>(){CallBase:true};

   public FooTestMeth()
   {
    //Arrange
    _mockedBarDataHandler.Setup(x=>x.Search(It.IsAny<int>).Returns(1);
    ...
    FooBusiness _fooBusiness = new FooBusiness();

    FooBusiness._barDatahandler = _mockedBarDataHandler.Object;

    //Act
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Constructor injection is one way, but you can also set a property. I don't like this, but this is another question. You need to remove the static keyword and _barDatahandler should be of type IBarDataHandler. Should work as expected.... Is there a reason why you want this public field to be static?

Comment: @Marc : No somebody long ago coded this and I should not change the business classes..  Why don't you put this in answer so that I can accept?

Comment: I posted my answer. You can mark as answered if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, there are multiple ways to achieve your needs.
Personally I like Shyju's answer more (Constructor Injection), but if you can't change the constructor, you can still change the implementation afterwards by setting the property:

business class:

```
public class FooBusiness
{
    private IBarDataHandler _barDatahandler = new BarDatahandler();

    public IBarDataHandler BarDatahandler
    {
        get { return _barDatahandler; }
        set { _barDatahandler = value; }
    }

    public int Search(int a)
    {
        return _barDatahandler.Search(a);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class FooBusinessTest
{
    _mockedBarDataHandler = new Mock<IBarDataHandler>(){CallBase:true};

    public FooTestMeth()
    {
        //Arrange
        _mockedBarDataHandler.Setup(x => x.Search(It.IsAny<int>).Returns(1);

        FooBusiness fooBusiness = new FooBusiness();
        fooBusiness.BarDatahandler = _mockedBarDataHandler.Object;

        //Act
    }
}
```

If you worry about to refactor the implementation, it is better to setup all the tests first. After that you can refactor with a safer feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your dataHandler dependency to  `FooBusiness`

You need to extract an interface for your `BarDataHandler` if one does not exist.

```
interface IBarDataHandler
{
  string GetUserToken(int id);
}
public class BarDataHandler : IBarDataHandler
{
  public string GetUserToken(int id)
  {
     // to do :read from db and return
  }
}
```

And add a constructor to `FooBusiness` class which accepts an implementation of `IBarDataHandler`.

```
public class FooBusiness
{
  IBarDataHandler barDataHandler;
  public FooBusiness(IBarDataHandler barDataHandler)
  {
    this.barDataHandler=barDataHandler
  }
  public string GetUserToken(int id)
  {
    return this.barDataHandler.GetUserToken(id);
  }
}
```

You can use any one of the dependency injection frameworks like Unity/Ninject/StructureMap to resolve your concrete implementation when your app runs.

You can use any mocking framework like **Moq** to mock the fake implementation of IBarDataHandler in your unittests.